# How to check if results are returned from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have this code running on a XAMPP server, which connects to a database in `db.php`.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();

$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$active = $_SESSION['active'];
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']))
{
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['email']); 
    $hash = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['hash']); 

    $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND active='1'");
    if (@@ROWCOUNT <> 1) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Account has already been activated";

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "/html/rtl/profile.php"
      </script>';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use an if-statement in PHP to see whether my MySQL search returns results, but it's not working. How would I do this?

Comment: change `if (@@ROWCOUNT <> 1 ) {` to  `if ($mysqli->num_rows > 0) {` and see how it works

Comment: `if (@@ROWCOUNT <> 1 ) {` - What's this? Errors should be displaying.

Comment: @Script47 I normally see that in sql server was a bit lost when i see this on mysql

Comment: thank you! @MasivuyeCokile it worked

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a compromised hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND active='1'");
if($query->num_rows<>1) {
   //Rest of the code
}
```